# Search a collection of objects

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to search for a collection of potential nodes but unable to do it...
I have a product that has a relationship with many instances. I would like to query the DB and get all the instances that are in a list that i get from the user.

Cypher:

```
var query = _context
 .Cypher
 .Start(new
 {
   instance = startBitsList,
   product = productNode.Reference,
 })
 .Match("(product)-[:HasInstanceRel]->(instance)")
 .Return(instance => instance.Node<ProductInstance>());
```

The problem is startBitsList... I use StringBuilder to generate a query that contains all the instances I'm looking for:

```
private static string CreateStartBits(IEnumerable<string> instanceNames)
 {
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.AppendFormat("node:'entity_Name_Index'(");
   foreach (var id in productIds)
   {
     sb.AppendFormat("Name={0} OR ", id);
   }
   sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 4);
   sb.Append(")");

  var startBitsList = sb.ToString();
  return startBitsList;
}
```

I get exceptions when trying to run this cypher...
Is there a better way to search for multiple items that are stored in the collection I get from the user?

Comment: Can instances be independent of Products? I.e. Can you have instance 'x' not connected to a product, or can an instance be connected to more than one product?

Comment: Each instance must be connected only to a single product

Comment: Have you tried the query in neo4j - does it work if you do something like : `START instance = /*multiple index look ups*/` ??

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think there are a couple of issues at play here, first I'm presuming you are using Neo4j 1.9 and not 2.0 - hence using the `.Start`.

Have you tried taking your query and running it in Neo4j? This should be your first port of call, typically it's easy to add a breakpoint on the `.Results` call and add a 'watch' for `query.Query.DebugText`.

However, I don't think you need to use the StartBits the way you are, I think you'd be better off filtering with a `.Where` as you already have the start point:

```
private static ICypherFluentQuery CreateWhereClause(ICypherFluentQuery query, ICollection<string> instanceNames)
{
    query = query.Where((Instance instance) => instance.Name == instanceNames.First());
    query = instanceNames.Skip(1).Aggregate(query, (current, localInstanceName) => current.OrWhere((Instance instance) => instance.Name == localInstanceName));
    return query;
}
```

and your query becomes something like:

```
var prodReference = new NodeReference<Product>(2);

var query =
    Client.Cypher
        .ParserVersion(1, 9)
        .Start(new {product = prodReference})
        .Match("(product)-[:HasInstanceRel]->(instance)");

query = CreateWhereClause(query, new[] {"Inst2", "Inst1"});
var resultsQuery = query.Return(instance => instance.As<Node<Instance>>());
```

2 things of note

1. We're not using the indexes - there is no benefit to using them as you have the start point and traversing to the 'instances' is a simple process for Neo4j.
2. The 'CreateWhereClause' method will probably go wrong if you pass in an empty list :)

The nice thing about not using the indexes is that - because they are legacy - you are set up better for Neo4j 2.0